# Buscar rango de números de dos dígitos con el comando sed

Tags: linux, regex, shell-script, sed

Tengo un archivo de texto con números del 0 al 500, cada número en una línea. Cada número puede aparecer solo, o pueden aparecer entre dos caracteres, o solo con uno o dos caracteres delante, o con uno o dos atrás.

El caso es que tengo que sustituir los números del 35 al 79 por "El número X no es válido".

He logrado sacar esos números, pero me coge los de 3 dígitos que contienen ese mismo patrón. ¿Cómo debería hacer para que solo me cogiese del 35 al 79, es decir, los de 2 dígitos?

Primero he probado haciendo lo siguiente para sacar los números del 35 al 39:

```
sed -r "s/([^1-5]*)([3][5-9])([^0-9]*)/\1[El numero \2 no es valido]\3/g"
```

Sin embargo, al hacer eso me coge del 35 al 39 pero también del 135 al 139, 235 a 239... Es decir, cualquier número que contenga 35, 36, 37, 38 o 39 independientemente de si antes o después tiene un número.

Comment: Evita ediciones dañinas y sin sentido a tu pregunta o serías reportado a los mods, ya que también si lo haces dejas *mal ubicada* a la respuesta dada

Answer (score 1):

A partir de tu comando, sugiero este:

```
sed -r "s/^((.?[^0-9])*)(3[5-9]|[4-7][0-9])(([^0-9].?)*)$/\1[El numero \2 no es valido]\3/" fichero
```

La clave está en la expresión regular:

```
^((.?[^0-9])*)(3[5-9]|[4-7][0-9])(([^0-9].*)?)$
```

Dice:

- `^(bloque1)(bloque2)(bloque3)$` coge todo en tres bloques, desde el principio al final de la línea
- bloque1: (.?[^0-9])*)` una serie de caracteres sin que termine en 0-9.
- bloque2: `3[5-9]|[4-7][0-9]` números 3X (X=5 a 9) o números XY con X=4 a 7 e Y=cualquier número. Esto encaja con los números 35 a 79.
- bloque3: `([^0-9].*)?` igual que el bloque1, pero pidiendo que después solo siga por algo no numérico. Es opcional.

En los comentarios has dejado un fichero de ejemplo:

```
^34
_35_
36
a37a
b38
75J
J76
K77L
78
M79N
80
B799L
esto es el 139
```

Lanzando mi comando contra él, me devuelve:

```
sed -r "s/^((.*[^0-9])?)(3[5-9]|[4-7][0-9])(([^0-9].*)?)$/\1[El numero \3 no es valido]\4/" fichero
^34
_[El numero 35 no es valido]_
[El numero 36 no es valido]
a[El numero 37 no es valido]a
b[El numero 38 no es valido]
[El numero 75 no es valido]
[El numero 75 no es valido]J
J[El numero 76 no es valido]
K[El numero 77 no es valido]L
[El numero 78 no es valido]
M[El numero 79 no es valido]N
80
B799L
esto es el 139
```

Comment: gracias, @Pollo. me encuentro que el capture group `\1` y `\3` no siempre encajan, cambiando a \4 funciona y me ha dejado pensativo. Probando en https://regex101.com/r/LQmCSD/1

Comment: Es correcto, es el `\4`... siempre de izquierda a derecha en el orden en el que aparecen los paréntesis: `^(grupo1(grupo2))(grupo3)(grupo4(grupo5))$`

Comment: @Pollo aaah ahora entiendo. Pensé que en `^(grupo1(cosas))` las `cosas` no sumaban un grupo más y el siguiente era `grupo2`.